# how to unmount disconnected USB drive in Bash for Windows

Tags: linux, windows-10, bash

My USB drive appears as a mounted drive in Bash for Windows 10:

```
ls /mnt
c  d
```

There is no `d` drive physically connected. I only have one internal hard drive `c`:

[image: win10 drives]

The `d` drive *was* connected in the past. How do I unmount it from Bash? Or maybe the better question is: if I connect/disconnect the USB drive often, do I need to manually eject/remove the drive from Bash every time as well?

Further, the mounted `d` drive contains quite a lot of data, even though it is not physically connected:

[image: d drive data]

I suppose something is being cached, but this is really inconvenient. I'd really like to reclaim this free space from my C drive on Windows. Any way to get rid of the `/mnt/d`?

Comment: You should be able to unmount the volume, exactly like you would unmount any volume, if you were using Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're sure you want to get rid of it and everything inside, you should be able to type

```
sudo rm -R /mnt/d
```

Comment: answered my question. still curious why the Linux subsystem kept those files around. perhaps I didn't remove the drive properly or something.

Comment: Yeah that does seem odd.  I don't know the answer to that either.  I looked in my own WSL, and there was a /mnt/g which I assume was left over from previously having a thumb drive attached.  However, it was empty.